# Chronic Rubygem returns 12pm when I give it a date, why not 0:00?

Tags: ruby

```
Chronic.parse("2011-03-10")
=> Thu Mar 10 12:00:00 -0600 2011
Time.parse("2011-03-10")
=> Thu Mar 10 00:00:00 -0600 2011
```

How do I fix that, it should be going to the beginning of the day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Internally, Chronic uses the complete time range given by the string, and will use the midpoint of that range as a guess for what you mean unless you tell it otherwise.

```
> Chronic.parse("2011-03-10", :guess => false).first
=> Thu Mar 10 00:00:00 +0000 2011
```

might be what you're after.